# Why when we conclude the conjunction "or" it becomes "and"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It's just a little problem, but makes me confusing.
For example consider this equation

$\begin{align}
&x^2-4=0\\
&\Leftrightarrow (x-2)(x+2)=0\\
&\Leftrightarrow (x-2)=0 \lor (x+2)=0\\
&\Leftrightarrow x=2 \lor x=-2\\
&\therefore \,\text{the value of } x\text{ that satisfy the equation is }x=2\land x=-2
\end{align}$

Why do we change the "or" conjuntion into "and" in conclusion?
Anyway, actually i took this problem from real analysis book by Julan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last sentence is wrong. It should also say "or" or maybe better, you should say the set of solutions is $\{2,-2\}$, not "and". So

$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}: x^2-4= 0\} = \{-2,2\}$$

It cannot be both at the same time, the "or" makes it a "union" (of two singletons).

Comment: Yep. It's a breakdown of colloquial English and rigorous mathematics. We tend to be loose with logical statements in everyday speech, like saying "this and that" when we really mean "this or that".